# Fluent Assertions: Equivalency of two lists of arrays, with arrays needing strict ordering

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to use Fluent Assertions to test a permutation generating algorithm. The algorithm generates a `List<int[]>`, where the `List` order does not matter, but the elements of each `int[]` do.

```c#
[Fact]
public void Are_all_permutations_generated()
{
    // Arrange
    var expected = new List<int[]>
    {
        new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
        new[] { 1, 3, 2 },
        new[] { 2, 1, 3 },
        new[] { 2, 3, 1 },
        new[] { 3, 1, 2 },
        new[] { 3, 2, 1 }
    };

    // Act
    var result = new List<int[]>
    {
        new[] { 3, 2, 1 },
        new[] { 1, 3, 2 },
        new[] { 2, 3, 1 },
        new[] { 2, 1, 3 },
        new[] { 3, 1, 2 },
        new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
    };

    // Assert
    result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
}
```

If I use `result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected)` as in the above code block it would pass even if `result` was

```c#
var result = new List<int[]>
{
    new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
};
```

How can I write the Fluent Assertions to allow any order for the list, but have strict ordering for the arrays so that it can assert all the permutations have been found? Is there someway of writing the `options` in the `BeEquivalentTo` to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WithStrictOrderingFor` to determine when you want to use strict ordering or not. It takes a lambda that gives you access to the `IObjectInfo`, an object that exposes all kinds of relevant information that you can use. Something like

```
WithStrictOrderingFor(info => info.RuntimeType == typeof(int[]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `WithStrictOrdering` on array assertion.

For example:

```
result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.WithStrictOrdering());
```

As well you can have a look at a [collection assertion docs](https://fluentassertions.com/collections/) from FluentAssertion, they provide more options on how to compare collections.

Comment: That does strict ordering on both the parent `List` and the child arrays. I want any order on the List and strict ordering on just the array elements.